# How is memcached different from other distributed caches?

Tags: caching, memcached, distributed

How is memcaches different (in terms of design/architecture/performance) from other in-memory distributed caches?

Thanks
Naresh

Answer (score 2):

Yours is too generic a question with no concrete correct answer. Memchaced is one of the distributed databases and you can find the [architecture overview here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached#Architecture). Others have similar architecture and sometimes servers can talk to each other too They are all implementation details and often gone by problem domain. But the underlying thing mostly is, they all are distributed key-value stores.

Comment: One key thing to note about memcached is the limit on element size.  From the above link.  >Keys are up to 250 bytes long and values can be at most 1 megabyte in size.